# Footer goes up when calling keyboard

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, styles

I'm trying to keep my footer fixed, but it goes up when I end up calling the keyboard. How do I solve this?

Code part:

```
<View style={{flex:1, flexDirection: 'row', position: 'absolute', bottom: 0}}>
    <Text style={styles.footerText}>Footer</Text>
</View>
```

in styles.footerText, it has only the color of the text.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XiZYt.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6L2fy.png)

Comment: can you create a pen please

Comment: whats ? a pen?? how to create a pen?

Comment: when we say pen(from codepen.io) or fiddle(from jsfiddle.net) we are talking about live code editor that gives you the opportunity to show your code and modifying it easy. This is one of my pen [link](https://codepen.io/cripava/pen/oNYqxRX) . You just need to register ,it's free.